# How to "Run ALL" in IPython Notebook in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

It might be a dull question, but I really did not find the answer for it.

I'm trying to migrate from browser edition to PyCharm of a IPython notebook. Thing is I can't find a "Run All" equivalent of the browser version. Do I have to run cell by cell everytime ?

thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Mac, use `Control + R`.

Reference: [v2016.3 tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/running-ipython-jupyter-notebook-cells.html#d332826e54). Verified that this works in v2017.1.

Comment: Ctrl+R doesn't seem to work for Windows in v2017.2. Still looking.

Answer (score 4):

Wondered the same (ages later). Just found out that in my PyCharm CE 2016.3 I can do `shift + F10` to run all cells.

Comment: It's `Run > Run All Cells` (the bottom-most entry in the menu). That and the very first entry is also `Shift+F10`, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

if you use netbeans type `F6`

Or `Run>Run All Cells`

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not appear to be available in PyCharm 2019.1, but will hopefully be there in 2019.2:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32071
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32007
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25443